# Plot two square lattices on top of one another

Tags: plotting, graphics, grid-lines

I plot two square lattices where one of them is rotated by 30 degrees. The Mathematica command to generate them is

```
{GridGraph[{5, 5}], Rotate[GridGraph[{5, 5}], 30]}
```

but I wonder whether it is possible to plot them right on top of each other to generate a Moire grid?

[see here for instance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern#/media/File:Moir%C3%A9_grid.svg)

Comment: @Syed you are a mathematica magician :) thanks

Comment: `Overlay[{GridGraph[{5, 5}], Rotate[GridGraph[{5, 5}], 45 Degree]}, 
 Alignment -> Center]` I forgot to write Degree, so deleted the previous comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
g1 = GridGraph[{5, 5}]
```

[image]

We can use [`RotationTransform`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RotationTransform.html) and [`GraphEmbedding`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphEmbedding.html) to rotate the vertex coordinates of the input graph:

```
ClearAll[rotateVCoords]

rotateVCoords[angle_: 30 Degree] := RotationTransform[angle, Mean @ #] @ 
  # &[GraphEmbedding @ #] &

SetProperty[g1, VertexCoordinates -> rotateVCoords[][g1]]
```

[image]

```
frames = Show[g1, 
    SetProperty[g1, VertexCoordinates -> rotateVCoords[# Degree][g1]],
     PlotRange -> MinMax /@ Transpose[rotateVCoords[45 Degree][g1]], 
    PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.05]] & /@ Range[0, 360, 3]; 

Export["rotatevcoords.gif", frames, AnimationRepetitions -> ∞]
```

[image]

We can use `rotateVCoords` in two ways: (1) With [`Show`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Show.html) + [`SetProperty`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetProperty.html) to get a `Graphics` object, (2) With [`GraphUnion`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphUnion.html) + [`IndexGraph`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/IndexGraph.html) to get a `Graph` object as output:

```
ClearAll[rotateAndCombineToGraphics, rotateAndCombineToGraph]

rotateAndCombineToGraphics[angle_: 30 Degree] := 
 Show[#, SetProperty[#, VertexCoordinates -> rotateVCoords[angle][#]]] &

rotateAndCombineToGraph[angle_: 30 Degree] := 
 GraphUnion[#, IndexGraph[#, 1 + VertexCount @ #], 
   VertexCoordinates -> Join[GraphEmbedding @ #, rotateVCoords[angle][#]], ##2] &
```

***Examples:***

```
rotateAndCombineToGraphics[] @ g1
```

[image]

```
Head @ %
```

> ```
> Graphics
> ```

```
rotateAndCombineToGraph[] @ g1
```

[image]

```
Head @ %
```

> ```
> Graph
> ```

With the second approach, we can add `Graph` options:

```
rotateAndCombineToGraph[][g1, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 VertexSize -> Scaled[.03], 
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[Mod[v, VertexCount[g1], 1], Center]}]
```

[image]

```
rotateAndCombineToGraph[45 Degree][g1, 
 ImageSize -> Large, 
 VertexSize -> Scaled[.03], 
 VertexLabels -> {v_ :> Placed[Mod[v, VertexCount[g1], 1], Center]}, 
 VertexStyle -> {v_ :> If[v > VertexCount[g1], Yellow, LightBlue]}, 
 EdgeStyle -> {_ :> Red, Alternatives @@ EdgeList[g1] :> Gray}]
```

[image]